# How to compute A and B in projection matrix

Tags: 3d, transformations, projections

I'm trying to compute a projection matrix to transform from view space to NDC with a near clip plane at -1 and far plane at +1. The general form of this matrix (disregarding aspect ratio and focal length) should be

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&A&B\\0&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

I followed SongHo's guide at http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html which sets $A=-(f+n)/(f-n)$ and $B=-2fn/(f-n)$.

However, setting the near clip plane at $n=-1$ and $f=-10$ (in view space) and using these $A$ and $B$, I get points with $z$ values on the interval $[-1, -10]$ transformed to $[3.04, 1.04]$ (after homogenisation).

When I do the derivations myself, I'd like to set $A=(n+f)/(n-f)$ and $B=(-2fn)/(n-f)$ instead, which indeed transforms to $[-1,1]$ instead.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A full perspective **projection** matrix is in the form of $M = M_{ortho}M_{persp}$ which is a orthographic matrix applied on a perspective matrix.

Comment: Also, the two sets of equations you have given are equivalent, you might have a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: Are they really equivalent, though? I mean, the first $B$ is $-2fn/(f-n) \neq -2fn/(n-f)$ (i.e., my $B$).

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere, your $B = \frac{-2fn}{f-n}$ is correct. Prehaps the -1 below the $A$ is causing this problem, in my derivation below it is 1, not -1.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'll be using column vector notation (eg. $Ax=y$), thus if you are using row notation, transpose the matrix and multiply from the left instead of the right. (eg. $y=x^TA^T$)

A perspective transformation matrix transforms a view frustum into a rectangular view volume. Note that the resulting view volume might **not** be a cube and might **not** be centered at 0.

One *example* of a perspective transformation matrix. There are **many more**, and yours is included.

Let $l=left,\\ r = right,\\ b = bottom,\\ t = top,\\ n = near,\\ f = far$

$M_{persp}=\begin{bmatrix}
1& & & \\
 &1& & \\
 & &\frac{n+f}{n}&-f\\
 & &\frac{1}{n}& 
\end{bmatrix}$

Since the resulting view volume is not the canonical view volume, we need to apply another matrix.

A orthographic transformation matrix transforms a rectangular view volume into a cubic view volume with two corners at (-1, -1, -1) and (1, 1, 1), which happens to be the canonical view volume.

Intuitively it will need one translation and one scaling.

$\text{T}_{ortho} = S\left(\frac{2}{r-l},\frac{2}{t-b},\frac{2}{n-f}\right)T\left(\frac{-(l+r)}{2},\frac{-(b+t)}{2}\frac{-(n+f)}{2}\right)$

$M_{ortho} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{r-l}& & & \\
    & \frac{2}{t-b} & & \\
    & & \frac{2}{n-f} & \\
    & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & & & \frac{-(l+r)}{2} \\
    & 1 & & \frac{-(b+t)}{2} \\
    & & 1 & \frac{-(n+f)}{2} \\
    & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$M_{ortho} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{r-l}& & & -\frac{l+r}{r-l} \\
    & \frac{2}{t-b} & & -\frac{t+b}{t-b} \\
    & & \frac{2}{n-f} & -\frac{n+f}{n-f}\\
    & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now you can combine them together to form a **perspective projection** matrix.

$M_{proj} = M_{ortho}M_{persp}$

$M_{proj} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{r-l}& & & -\frac{l+r}{r-l} \\
    & \frac{2}{t-b} & & -\frac{t+b}{t-b} \\
    & & \frac{2}{n-f} & -\frac{n+f}{n-f}\\
    & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1& & & \\
 &1& & \\
 & &\frac{n+f}{n}&-f\\
 & &\frac{1}{n}& 
\end{bmatrix}$

$M_{proj} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2n}{r-l}& & \frac{l+r}{l-r} & \\
    & \frac{2n}{t-b} & \frac{b+t}{b-t} & \\
    & & \frac{n+f}{n-f} & \frac{2fn}{f-n}\\
    & & 1 &
\end{bmatrix}$

If you have a free-moving camera you will need a camera matrix too, thus the final projection matrix centered on the camera is.

$M_{proj} = M_{ortho}M_{persp}M_{camera}$

Comment: Thanks! But what does my matrix do, then? Doesn't it transform from a view space (with a perspective camera at the origin looking into -z) to a "clip space" (rectangular view volume) where far points have larger z values?

Comment: If your far plane is behind the near plane, far points will have smaller values, but after applying the orthographic transformation matrix it will flip back.

Comment: I misread your equation, what you have given is indeed a projection matrix, but a very simplified one, where r = -l, t = -b and n < f. Your two sets of equations are equivalent too, so the mistake is not in the matrix, it should be elsewhere.